# Model OCL evaluation vs Object evaluation

Tags: java, emf, ocl

I need to check if a model fires one or more OCL constraints.
Models are stored in XMI, loaded with EMF. OCL constraints are generated automatically (String or the like).

I found a way to check a constraint on an EObject

```
helper.setContext(ecClass);
query = helper.createQuery(expression);
Object o = ocl.check(eo, invariant);
```

o then contains the result : true or false.

Do I have to check every object of the model 'by hand' or is there a way, a method or a class that would make it directly (and probably more efficiently) ?

Note that :
 - No modelling information is hard-coded : metamodels, models and OCL are manipulated in the most generic way,
 - I work on a standalone soft : all jars are added specifically. I've tried to use DresdenOCL, but I don't know why the registering of the packages is troublesome.

Comment: Do you mean "violates" by "fires"?
Do you require the OCL validation to be triggered from Java code? The latter question because if you dont mind using Eclipse then validation is easily doable and you can test all instances of a given class using universal quantification in OCL.

Comment: Yes, I mean "violates" (but the word is a bit heavy). And, no, I do mind not using Eclipse. Standalones sound easier to execute on a calculator (I might be wrong though).

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "registering of the packages is troublesom" in your original question. Also I do not understand what you mean by "easier to execute on a calculator." Will you elaborate? I can write an answer in which I show how to evaluate OCL constraints on instances of Ecore models using Eclipse, using a simple dummy example (like checking that all instances of cars have 4 mounted tires). The other option would be for you to share some of the models you have (and corresponding Ecore models) as well as a few OCL constraints -- i could write an answer based on that.

Comment: Working programmatically on the automatic learning of OCL rules, I don't use GUI plugins nor Eclipse 'integration' to allow me a standalone execution. Personal hygiene concern.

Comment: Working programmatically on the automatic learning of OCL rules, I don't use GUI plugins nor Eclipse 'integration' to allow me a standalone execution. Personal hygiene concern. About "registering packages", it's a running gag in Eclipse to hunt for the "register metamodel" button in the Modelling Framework. Programmatically, I do it, but it is still not completely sure to me how does it work - but this works fine and stands hard testbench. To answer my problem, I execute OCL rule where they can be applied (information I have do to the use of patterns of higher order). Hope you get my point.

Comment: Sorry Stack Overflow police, I'm not use to the "SMS" writing as allowed by the comment system.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements (when and where to check objects) you may try to use Notifications and/or add some logic to your own EObject implementation extending EMF EObject.

Comment: Which is more or less what I've done : a loop on the objects that check them one after another. As I don't necessarily need to check them all, this version works actually very well.